# How to inject a ViewModel with Koin in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, koin

How do we inject ViewModel with dependency using Koin?

So For Example I have a `ViewModel` thats like this:

```
class SomeViewModel(val someDependency: SomeDependency, val anotherDependency: AnotherDependency): ViewModel()
```

Now the official docs [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/quick-references/koin-for-android/), states that to provide a `ViewModel` we could do something like:

```
val myModule : Module = applicationContext {

    // ViewModel instance of MyViewModel
    // get() will resolve Repository instance
    viewModel { SomeViewModel(get(), get()) }

    // Single instance of SomeDependency
    single<SomeDependency> { SomeDependency() }

    // Single instance of AnotherDependency
    single<AnotherDependency> { AnotherDependency() }
}
```

Then to inject it, we can do something like:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    // Lazy inject SomeViewModel
    val model : SomeViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // or also direct retrieve instance
        val model : SomeViewModel= getViewModel()
    }
}
```

The confusing part for me is that, normally you will need a `ViewModelFactory` to provide the `ViewModel` with Dependencies. Where is the `ViewModelFactory` here? is it no longer needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello viewmodel() it's a Domain Specific Language (DSL) keywords that help creating a ViewModel instance.

At this [link][1] of official documentation you can find more info

> The viewModel keyword helps declaring a factory instance of ViewModel.
> This instance will be handled by internal ViewModelFactory and
> reattach ViewModel instance if needed.

this example of koin version 2.0 [1]: https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html#_viewmodel_dsl

```
// Given some classes 
class Controller(val service : BusinessService) 
class BusinessService() 

// just declare it 
val myModule = module { 
  single { Controller(get()) } 
  single { BusinessService() } 
}
```

Comment: I see. Thats the first time I see that documentation so thanks!

Comment: you can find all reference [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/reference-documentation)

Comment: Documentation can now be found [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel)